# How to debug when running Robolectric tests in Android Studio?

Tags: android, debugging, gradle, android-studio, robolectric

I need to run debug while my tests execution in Android Studio + Robolectric.
Each time I try to run them by selecting `debug` for the `test` task from Gradle tasks I get the error message:

> Error running package_name:app_name [test]: Unable to open debugger
>   port : java.net.SocketException "Socket closed"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I found the reason of the error. To make it run you need to uncheck the "Use in-process build" option in Compiler -> Gradle settings of Android Studio.

[image]

Comment: @HeathBorders can you please post detail how to make this work on Intellij

Comment: I don't remember now. I hope past me would have added more notes or a different answer if there were more steps.

Comment: This slows down the build, so I hope Google comes around to fix this in Android Studio. @HeathBorders: IntelliJ IDEA does not have this issue, as it doesn't support In-process build in the first place.

Comment: This does not help me. Running Android Studio 1.1.0

Comment: Where can I find this setting? Sorry I'm very new to Android Studio, and I don't like Android in general :P

Comment: This doesn't seem to apply any more in IntelliJ 2016.3.3

Comment: This setting seems to have disappeared in Android Studio v1.3. Here is a workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31570957/1434060

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error on linux, and the problem was that the another previous process has taken the port and hung.
So, the solution is a netstat to locate the process blocking the port, then kill this process, or you can restart the machine.