# Use in process-build disappeared in Android Studio v1.3

Tags: android, android-studio, robolectric

I have recently updated my Android Studio to 1.3 in Beta channel, and I noticed that `Use in process-build` has been disappeared from Compiler -> Gradle settings menu. Then I wonder how can I debug my Robolectric test considering a known issue as explained in [How to debug when running Robolectric tests in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21184490/how-to-debug-when-running-robolectric-tests-in-android-studio) and http://www.culmination.org/2014/03/debugging-during-robolectric-test-execution-in-android-studio/

I receive `java.net.SocketException "Socket closed"` error and I do not know how to disable `Use in process-build`.

[Issue tracking](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=179151&q=Use%20in%20process-build%20disappeared&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)

Answer (score 5):

My team has also been experiencing this issue with Android Studio 1.3 and were able to fix the issue by modifying the following file:

```
<project-folder>
|-- .idea
    |-- workspace.xml
```

Just add the following component at the very top, just inside the project tag:

```
<project version="4">
  <component name="AndroidGradleBuildConfiguration">
    <option name="USE_EXPERIMENTAL_FASTER_BUILD" value="false" />
  </component>
  ...
</project>
```